# Is there any way to assemble only one flavor of the androidTest builds?

Tags: android

I have three flavors in my Android project. How can I build just one of them for my instrumentation tests ("androidTest" build artifact)?

When I run the gradle task `assembleAndroidTest` with Android Studio 2.0 Beta 2 I get three outputs - one for each of my flavors:

```
myproject-dev-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
myproject-itest-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
myproject-production-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
```

What if I just want to build one of them? I don't want to wait 3x the build time for building stuff I don't need (yea it's that bad).

Here is the list of all gradle tasks that contain the name "androidTest":

```
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
compileDebugAndroidTestSources
compileDevDebugAndroidTestSources
compileItestDebugAndroidTestSources
compileProductionDebugAndroidTestSources
compileTelenorDebugAndroidTestSources
installDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
installDevDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the DevDebug build.
installItestDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the ItestDebug build.
installProductionDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the ProductionDebug build.
installTelenorDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the TelenorDebug build.
uninstallDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallDevDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the DevDebug build.
uninstallItestDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the ItestDebug build.
uninstallProductionDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the ProductionDebug build.
uninstallTelenorDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the TelenorDebug build.
connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices.
connectedDebugAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for debug on connected devices.
connectedDevDebugAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for devDebug on connected devices.
connectedItestDebugAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for itestDebug on connected devices.
connectedProductionDebugAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for productionDebug on connected devices.
connectedTelenorDebugAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for telenorDebug on connected devices.
deviceAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests using all Device Providers.
spoonDevDebugAndroidTest - Run all instrumentation tests on all connected devices for 'DevDebugAndroidTest'
spoonItestDebugAndroidTest - Run all instrumentation tests on all connected devices for 'ItestDebugAndroidTest'
spoonProductionDebugAndroidTest - Run all instrumentation tests on all connected devices for 'ProductionDebugAndroidTest'
spoonTelenorDebugAndroidTest - Run all instrumentation tests on all connected devices for 'TelenorDebugAndroidTest'
compileRetrolambdaDebugAndroidTest
compileRetrolambdaDevDebugAndroidTest
compileRetrolambdaItestDebugAndroidTest
compileRetrolambdaProductionDebugAndroidTest
compileRetrolambdaTelenorDebugAndroidTest
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If flavor = "flavor" and type = "debug", then try:

```
./gradlew assembleFlavorDebugAndroidTest
```

Comment: I have a custom buildType called "demo" and when i do assembleFlavourDemoAndroidTest, it says this gradle task does not exist?

Comment: Indeed, the gradle task `assembleFlavourXXXXAndroidTest`  won't exist. Only `assembleFlavorDebugAndroidTest` is generated. 
Does somebody know why ?Is possible to change it ?

Comment: @jonney, Jack did you resolve ot? I have the same issue. Maybe there is a way to recreate such a task knowing how assembleFlavorDebugAndroidTest would look like?

Comment: No I did not fix it

Comment: @jonney found out how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/57786087/1118475

Answer (score 2):

Found out how to do it for any build type, not just `debug`. Tests are only created for a single build type, by default it's `debug`, but it can be changed. In app build.gradle you need to add:

```
android { 

    testBuildType "myownbuildtype"
    ...
}
```

Then you should be able to do `./gradlew assembleMyflavorMyownbuildtypeAndroidTest`

Comment: When trying to do this with a flavor, I get the following error:

`Test Build Type 'releaseTest' does not exist.`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What do you put in `testBuildType` and how does your gradle command look like, then?